# grep with negative condition, and more than a certain line number

Tags: shell, unix, sed, awk, grep

i'm trying to write a grep/sed/awk for a condition from a file, and at the same time with a negative condition (does not contain xxx) and also i wanna grep all the lines that are > than a certain line number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awk should deal with that nicely:

```sh
/condition/ && ! /negative condition/ { print $0; outputdone = 1 }

{ if(NR > certain_line_number && !outputdone) print $0
  outputdone = 0
}
```

I wasn't quite certain if all the conditions were applied together. I guessed that you always want to print lines beyond some point, but up to that point the positive and negative conditions applied.

Comment: You could shorten that to `awk '(/condition/&&!/negative condition/)||NR>certain_line_number)'`. You still could include your `outputdone` flag but I do not see why one should need that.

Answer (score 0):

```
tail -<number of lines that you want from end of file>  filename | grep -v xxx
```

Comment: this is nicer but doesn't work for me cos i save the last line i read and the file continues to grow, so technically i wouldn't know the number of lines i need to read

Comment: This also does not include the (positive) condition requested by the OP.